# My virtual QWERTY keyboard has vanished

Tags: keyboard, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have an Xperia X10.
Suddenly my virtual QWERTY keyboard has vanished and has been replaced by some other layout.

When I enter the "Contacts" list an try to edit  I now get a standard phone keyboard layout instead of the QWERTY one.

What could have happened?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the contact's phone number or some other piece of information?

Comment: Other info. I have looked around a bit more and it seems my phone has somehow become Chinese keyboard! Can't get Hebrew at all now.

Comment: SOLVED! Seems that somehow I changed my "Input Method" to Chinese. :(

Comment: @theblitz: Please enter that as an answer and "accept" it. This will help future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you long click on a text box, you have the option to change the keyboard to any you have enabled under `Settings -> Language & Keyboard`. Maybe you accidentally switched it ;)